# Flask not updating webpage to reflect changes in application.py

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I'm running this very simple application.py file, in debug mode, on my Mac.

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret"
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

It shows up on 127.0.0.1:5000. When I change `return "hello"` to `return "goodbye"` and refresh the page, nothing happens. When I try to `return render_template(goodbye.html)` from my templates directory, nothing happens. I even changed the route from '/' to '/bbbb' and nothing changed. I see a bunch of GET requests in my terminal, each with a status code of 200.

I've **never** had this problem with Flask, that is until I tried to use sockets.io. Any thoughts on what is happening?

Comment: I tested this on my machine, and it works when I change `return "hello"` to `return "goodbye"`. Could you try cleaning your browser cache and testing again?

Comment: Sure. I've been hitting shift + enter, which should do it, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: Nope. No change.

Comment: It's like the server reads the file once on start-up and then ignores it completely.

Comment: I tested it many times on my computer, and it works fine everytime using your code. Could you check your flask and flask-socketio versions, mine are: `Flask==1.0.2
Flask-SocketIO==3.0.1`

Comment: @Ryan What command are you using to run the app ?

Comment: @VishvajitPathak flask run

Comment: @alessandrocb same flask version as you, I assume most recent version of socekt IO. I just installed it today.

Comment: @Ryan Are you sure that you are running the exactly same code on your machine as the code you posted here ?
Even I have `Flask==1.0.2 Flask-SocketIO==3.0.1` and it works fine.

Comment: @VishvajitPathak Yes, absolutely, no changes.

Comment: @VishvajitPathak And when I comment out everything that references sockets-io, it works as expected! But I need sockets-io.

Comment: @Ryan Try this command `python you_file_name_here.py` to run the app.
Also post here the output of `pip freeze` command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179331/discussion-between-ryan-and-vishvajit-pathak).

Comment: @Ryan if you have gevent or eventlet installed, make sure you monkey patch the standard library if you use the Flask reloader.

Comment: @Miguel not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Ryan do you have eventlet or gevent installed in your virtual environment? If you don't then ignore my previous comment. If you do, read the documentation on "monkey patching" for the one that you have installed.